# Is it possible to assert that a mocked method was called with the return value of another mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

Is there any possible way to test code that passes the result of one method to another? I know it's not advisable to test the internal mechanics of a method, but in this case, the only output is a side effect, so I can't assert on the result.

```
@mock.patch("myclass.client")
def test_stuff(self, mock_client):
    TEST_THING = 'foo'
    mock_client.get_thing.return_value = TEST_THING
    mock_client.get_another_thing.return_value = True

    class_under_test.do_something()
    mock_client.get_another_thing.assert_called_with(TEST_THING) // Fails, since return value is wrapped in a magic mock
```

Comment: Can you include `class_under_test`?  Are you sure that you're patching it correctly and that `mock_client.get_thing` is being called at all?

Comment: I realized what I was doing wrong, it seems that python does not support mocking methods with specific parameters.

Comment: You can mock/patch pretty much anything in a Python unit test, but you'll need to expand your question a bit with a minimum reproducible example to illustrate what it is you're trying to do.  Again, not being able to see `myclass` or how `class_under_test` is constructed makes it hard to debug your issue.  :)